# Exim: how to log email body

Tags: debian, exim

How can I log the **body** of an email in Exim?

My specific need is to trace why an email from user `www-data` is being generated every so often - I can see the record of its delivery in the Exim logs, but not what's in it.

I'm on Debian Jessie, and using the split configuration.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if it's possible to write the contents of a mail to exim's log, but even if it is, I would recommend against it since it would make your logs fairly unreadable.

However, exim has a `shadow_transport` option which you can set on another transport, and which would allow you to write the contents of a mail to a local mailbox for later reference; this should allow you to do what you want to do. For more information, check out [this](http://www.exim.org/exim-html-1.90/doc/html/spec_14.html#SEC349) part of the exim specification.

Note though that some jurisdictions may not look kindly on this type of casual intrusion of your users' privacy. If in doubt, contact your lawyer.